# Templates - No matching Function for call to

Tags: c++, templates

I was writing what I thought was the following simple example:

```
template <typename ARCHIVE>
void serialize(ARCHIVE& archive, int v)
{
    archive.serialize(v);
}

class Serializer
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void serialize(const T& v)
    {
        ::serialize(*this, v);
    }
};

template <>
void Serializer::serialize<int>(const int& v)
{
    
}

struct Test
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

template <typename ARCHIVE>
void serialize(ARCHIVE& archive, const Test& v)
{
    archive.serialize(v.a);
    archive.serialize(v.b);
    archive.serialize(v.c);
}

void bar()
{
    Test t;
    Serializer s;
    
    s.serialize(t);
}

int main()
{
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

But keep getting the following error

```
b.cpp: In instantiation of 'void Serializer::serialize(const T&) [with T = Test]':
b.cpp:43:13:   required from here
b.cpp:13:28: error: no matching function for call to 'serialize(Serializer&, const Test&)'
   13 |                 ::serialize(*this, v);
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
b.cpp:2:6: note: candidate: 'template<class ARCHIVE> void serialize(ARCHIVE&, int)'
    2 | void serialize(ARCHIVE& archive, int v)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~
b.cpp:2:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
b.cpp:13:28: note:   cannot convert 'v' (type 'const Test') to type 'int'
   13 |                 ::serialize(*this, v);
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

I was under the impression that the template method `Serializer::serialize` is not compiled until it is used by a specific type.  Thus, by the time `bar()` tries to call `Serializer::serialize<Test>()`, the method void `serialize(ARCHIVE& archive, const Test& v)` already exists.

If I remove the `void serialize(ARCHIVE& archive, int v)` method, things get (in my mind) even stranger with the following error:

```
b.cpp: In member function 'void Serializer::serialize(const T&)':
b.cpp:15:19: error: '::serialize' has not been declared; did you mean 'Serializer'?
   15 |                 ::serialize(*this, v);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~
      |                   Serializer
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Reordering the definitions makes your code compile, BTW. I put `Test` first, then both `::serialize(....)` functions, then the serializer class and rest. Perhaps the definitions of `::serialize(....)` must be both in scope at the definition point of the method `serialize(....)` (?)

Comment: As described in the duplicate target, name lookup doesn't find the template taking a `Test` as the  2nd argument. You need to order the templates in the source accordingly.